# creating childern from xaml and C# Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin

I have 2 labels in my Xamarin forms page which are added from Xaml 
I want to add a new label from C#
How is that possible?

Xaml Code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="Lecture11.Page1">
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="Label from Xaml" />
                <Label Text="Hi There!!"
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
`
```

C# Code:

```
 public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
    {
        public Page1 ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();

            //Code to add the label to the page.....?
        }
        Label _lblNew = new Label
        {
            Text = "Label from C#",
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,

        };
    }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You would normally just create an instance of a 'Label' with whatever attributes you need it to have.

```
Label newLabel = new Label {
            Text = "Hello, Forms!",
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize (NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)),
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
        },
```

Then you simply add it to your view, it might be that your other labels are in a vertical stack layout, in which case you just have to add it to the stack layout in the position you'd like it.

```
mainStackLayout.Children.Add(newLabel);
```

Please find the Xamarin developer centre guide to the labels control [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Label/).

Comment: I may not explained it well, thank for the answer but i already tried it before posting the question ... the real issue is i have to create a new instance of mainStackLayout , content page , page whatever in order to add children into it through C# and that makes the problem the new layout will override what i build in XAML thanks again bro

Comment: I would perhaps suggest adding some of your code into your post, that relates to the problem, it may help us figure out a solution for you.